# Only a hard refresh will display the updated WordPress site

Tags: wordpress, caching

I cloned a website using the duplicator plugin and made changes to it. When logged in as admin I see the changes but when I use an incognito browser it still shows the cloned version (old version). I can see the changes when I do a hard refresh of the browser, but refreshing again reverts to the old copy. I tried emptying the cache, deleting cookies, deleting cache folder on `wp-content` but nothing seems to work?

I don't have any caching plugins installed.

The css changes seem to take effect, but the old pages are still loading.
It seems like the pages are somehow cached somewhere.

I had the hosting support check and they updated the A records but it still somehow doesn't fix the issue.

It's in a shared hosting on hostgator

Thank you.

Comment: Though this question does not follow guidelines of this forum, but you seem to be freshie. Just check if you are using cache plugin, then disable that for time being unless you follow proper documentation of that plugin and complete know-how about clearing cache.

Comment: Thank you. No caching plugin was used? It's really weird, I can only see the updated website on hard refresh of a browser.

Comment: Check from the hosting dashboard if there is a possibility to empty cache.

Comment: I already did and it has no option for it. :(

Answer (score 0):

Though this question does not follow guidelines of this forum, but you seem to be freshie. Just check if you are using cache plugin, then disable that for time being unless you follow proper documentation of that plugin and complete know-how about clearing cache.

Answer (score 0):

By any change are you using wp fastest cache or W3 Total Cache plugins.

Please double check you are not using any cache plugins

make sure you dint enabled the cache in wp_config file

```
define('WP_CACHE', true);
```

Comment: I didn't use any caching plugin and nothing like that on the config file.